# Date.ToLongDateString() returning date in German only on prod environment (8.2)

Tags: multilingual

I have a listing page for articles that includes the date, converted into a long date string ("Friday, December 21 2018"). On all of my lower environments it is showing the dates in English but on prod it is showing the date in German.

```
date.Text = item.Date.ToLongDateString();
```

The site doesn't even use German as a language, just English and French. The listing page and all story items are English. I figure this must be an environmental Sitecore issue, since it shows in English on all lower environments. What could be causing this, and can I fix it without a code change?

Comment: Have you checked the culture settings of the production server? I wonder if it's set to German.

Comment: would that be settings in Sitecore, or on the server itself? I believe the server is located in Germany so that would make sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`date.ToLongDateString()` executes in the background `DateTimeFormat.Format(this, "D", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)`.

It means that the culture info is taken from the thread or from the server (you may want to double check if it's from both or from one of them only - I'm not sure anymore).

What you could do is passing the chosen culture to the `Format` method like

```
DateTimeFormat.Format(this, "D", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

But that requires code change.

It should be also enough to set the globalization in web.config like:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB">
```

I didn't have an option to test it though

Comment: thanks! now, my site does have both English and French. would adding "<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" mess up the French version (i.e. make the culture context english when it should be French)?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be possible to get the language automatically from the Sitecore context. You may try using "auto" instead of "en-GB" but I'm afraid you would need to change your code and pass the culture info.

Comment: ok. i'll just go wtih the code change then. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set language property to proper language code dor tour english anf french sites like this:

`<site name="french" ... virtualFolder="/fr-FR" physicalFolder="/fr-FR" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/French/Home" language="fr-FR" ... />
<site name="english" ... virtualFolder="/en-GB" physicalFolder="/en-GB" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/English/Home" language="en-GB" ... />`

Don't know your current setup of sites in config so take above configuration as example and especially mind the `language` attribute.

Then you can access this within your code like this `Sitecore.Context.Language`.

Therefore the code to format datetime field should be like:

`DateTimeFormat.Format(this, "D", new CultureInfo(Sitecore.Context.Language));`